# How to show losses when running validation (val.py) on a testing dataset in Ultralytics YOLOv5?

Tags: object-detection, yolov5

I would like to show the classification and localization loss my model has when I evaluate it on my testing dataset using `val.py`. However, it seems that val.py only shows the object detection metrics. Is there a workaround to this?

Basically, I would like to display the losses during training as shown in the snippet below:

[image]

to the output of val.py when running it to a testing dataset as shown below:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might wok for you
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o6vU.png)

On val.py there are the following lines to get the losses already wrote [lines 212-214 on the git version i have from ultralytics]:

```
    if compute_loss:
        loss += compute_loss(train_out, targets)[1]  # box, obj, cls
```

However, compute loss must be initialized before the for loop for the batches. To do that import `ComputeLoss` from the `utils.py` file and pass `model.model` as an argument. This is so because in `val.py` model is a distributed object that raises an error if it is not done like this. I modified lines 191-198 of the original file, the ones that define the progress bar. I added the `compute_loss` initialization and the losses to the progress bar

```
s = ('%22s' + '%11s' * 9) % ('Class', 'Images', 'Instances', 'P', 'R', 'mAP50', 'mAP50-95','box_loss','obj_loss','class_loss')
tp, fp, p, r, f1, mp, mr, map50, ap50, map = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
dt = Profile(), Profile(), Profile()  # profiling times
loss = torch.zeros(3, device=device)
jdict, stats, ap, ap_class = [], [], [], []
callbacks.run('on_val_start')
pbar = tqdm(dataloader, desc=s, bar_format='{l_bar}{bar:10}{r_bar}{bar:-10b}')  # progress bar

compute_loss = ComputeLoss(model.model)

for batch_i, (im, targets, paths, shapes) in enumerate(pbar):
```

Now on the variable loss you have the 3 losses accumulated with each batch.
When the for loop ends i added the get loss lines before printing the results [281-285 of the orinial file]:

```
# Get Loss
box_loss = loss.cpu().numpy()[0]*batch_size/len(dataloader)
obj_loss = loss.cpu().numpy()[1]*batch_size/len(dataloader)
cls_loss = loss.cpu().numpy()[2]*batch_size/len(dataloader)

# Print results
pf = '%22s' + '%11i' * 2 + '%11.3g' * 7  # print format
LOGGER.info(pf % ('all', seen, nt.sum(), mp, mr, map50, map, box_loss, obj_loss, cls_loss))
if nt.sum() == 0:
    LOGGER.warning(f'WARNING: no labels found in {task} set, can not compute metrics without labels ⚠️')
```

I multiplied by the batch size and divided by the dataloader length to get the average loss per image as the loss items are the total losses accumulated during the processing of the whole dataset.

Hope it works for you too.